# Bootstrap 3 static sidebar with image background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been experimenting with different layouts with Bootstrap, and I happened across this site: [Punkchip.com](http://www.punkchip.com/why-dont-you-use-bootstrap/). I've attempted it with a dual-column grid system (which is easy enough), but how would I go about replicating the left-hand column (including image and text)? (The subject of the article is a little ironic)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the website they're are using two columns with two different styles, first one is the "site-header" which has the following style:

```
@media (min-width: 900px)
.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 40%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: none;
}
```

the second column named "site-main" and has the following style:

```
@media (min-width: 900px)
    .site-main{
        width: 60%;
        margin-left: 40%;
    }
```

and the html code for the page is something similar to this:

```
<header class="site-header">...</header>
<div class="site-main">...</div>
```